# How to link multiple layer masks to multiple layers in photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I'm using PS 2017 but the question is for any version actually. I am looking for a way in PS, even if someone knows of an action or script, to create links between layers and their layer-masks and not have to click in between each one manually. I'm sure my question is understandable but here is the before and after I'm talking about:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't understand the -1 score. Is this not a legitimate question?

Comment: A question about relinking layer masks is answered [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4628461#4628461) You could find the code that sets the link and apply it to your own script

Answer (score 0):

This will unlink all layer masks. The script however will NOT work for groups.

```
// Call the source doc
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--)
{
    try
    {
        link(i, false); // this will unlink them all
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        // no layer mask!
    }
}

function link(idx, setlink)
{  
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();   
    var ref = new ActionReference();   
    ref.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), idx );   
    desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID('null'), ref );   
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();   
    desc2.putBoolean( charIDToTypeID('Usrs'), setlink);   
    desc.putObject( charIDToTypeID('T   '), charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), desc2 );   
    executeAction( charIDToTypeID('setd'), desc, DialogModes.NO );   
}
```